# Why does not compile?

Tags: chessboard

In the example on page 71 of the book: Chessboard: A package to print
chessboards, by Ulrike Fischer, May 1, 2014,  there is an example[image]

When I compile it only appears the following picture. Why?\

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ps]{skak}
\newchessgame
\includegraphics
[scale=0.477,viewport=20
17 20
17]
{inputs/brett}%
\chessboard[showmover=false,
border=false,
label=false,
boardfontencoding=LSBC5,
boardfontsize=20pt,
whitepiececolor=brown!70,
blackpiececolor=black,
setfontcolors]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You do not have the file `input/brett` I guess. + Your example cannot be compiled, at least the `\begin{document}` is missing (Christian Hupfer just edited your post to enclose the code in a `code` environment).

Comment: @Clément: Yes, that is probably the case. On the other hand, it should fail to compile at all, if the file is not present

Comment: What does the `log` files says? Maybe that error is handled / eaten by the `\newchessgame` command.

Comment: It's true, I forgot \begin {document}. But even putting it, he keeps giving the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inputs/brett` is the full path to the nice chessboard image you found in the manual. The error, as Christian an Clément pointed out, is raised because, well, you don't have that specific file.

The solution is: find a chessboard image and use it instead. Pretty much it. `:)`

For example, consider this image (courtesy of Google Images):

[image: board]

Then you can make some adjustments in your own code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.605,viewport=0 18 -20 0]{board.jpg}
\newchessgame
\chessboard[
    showmover=false,
    border=false,
    label=false,
    boardfontsize=20pt,
    whitepiececolor=white,
    blackpiececolor=black,
    setfontcolors]

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: Result]

***Note:*** Sorry for the bad alignment, I'm terrible at fixing the viewport points (see the `viewport` key in the included image). But hopefully you get the idea.

Hopefully it helps. `:)`

<sub>Check and mate. `:)` I'm marking this question as CW because I don't feel like this answer is a 100% correct. Anyway.</sub>